# VBA SQL INSERT command failing on DTG

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, sql-insert, ms-access-2013

Ok so once again I have to call on the masses to figure out my mess up.. I know it has to be something quite stupid on my part but I have been looking and staring at the same line of code for a little while not achieving much. I did refer to this article [Inserting current DateTime into Audit table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11084663/inserting-current-datetime-into-audit-table) and that didn't solve my problem. I know for a fact that the DTG is what is failing the INSERT statement. Here is my code followed by the output:

```
sqlStr = "INSERT INTO USys_ApplicationLogs (Application_ID, TimeStamp) " & _
        "VALUES (" & ConfigurationHandler.GetSetting("ModID") & ", " & Format(Now(), "\#yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss\#") & ");"

CurrentDb.Execute sqlStr
' OUTPUT: INSERT INTO USys_ApplicationLogs (Application_ID, TimeStamp) VALUES ({00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}, #2017-10-27 23:01:24#);
```

Now it should be noted that I am doing this as a application log and the GUID has been obfuscated but that does not generate the error.

**EDIT:** This problem was caused due to me using the reserved Access 2016 word *TIMESTAMP* as a field in my table. Just to let others know if they encounter this problem.

Comment: Then use `[TimeStamp]`.

Comment: I could but it would be safer to rename to a non reserved word

Comment: Simpler perhaps, but not safer.